# NSPredicate case insensitive string search with CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, cloudkit

I'm trying to search a String field of a CloudKit object. The following line successfully compiles and runs without error.

```
NSPredicate(format: "Title BEGINSWITH %@", "Apple")
```

Yet, when I try add case insensitive search, it the app crashes.

```
NSPredicate(format: "Title BEGINSWITH[cdl] %@", "Apple")
```

With error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CKException', reason: 'Invalid predicate: Title BEGINSWITH[cdl] "Apple" (Error Domain=CKErrorDomain Code=12 "Invalid operator in <Title BEGINSWITH[cdl] "Apple">: Unsupported operator: BEGINSWITH" UserInfo=0x7fb69d02e910 {ck_isComparisonError=true, NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid operator in <Title BEGINSWITH[cdl] "Apple">: Unsupported operator: BEGINSWITH, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fb69d02e9e0 "Unsupported operator: BEGINSWITH"})'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As from the documentation on CKQuery:
"String-based comparisons are case insensitive but otherwise all comparisons must be an exact match of the specified value."

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKQuery_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CKQuery

So I think BEGINSWITH is all you should need. Have you not found this to be the case?

Comment: Sweet! Must have misread the docs the first time through. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not getting a case-insensitive match with BEGINSWITH on development. Did something change in the last 5 years?

Comment: BEGINSWITH is **case-sensitive**. From Apple: _"... When using this operator, the field must contain a string value and must start with the string you specify. **Matches are case-sensitive**..."_ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckquery#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CKQuery